# Is it not possible to call another JInternalFrame or JPanel [saved as NewJIF.java]from the main JFrame[saved as MainJFrame.java] in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I have created a MainJFrame.java in the package myproject using New project->java->java aplication and NewJIF.java in the same package.

When a JButton clicked in MainJFrame.java i want JInterFrame to open using 
new NewJIF().setVisible(true); inside actionPerformed() method.

But this is not working ...and caught some people saying this is impossible in netbeans to call another java class using swing framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it is possible. You can add any code you want to an ActionListener. So there is no reason you can't do this.

I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). Understand how the code in the ActionListener works there and then incorporate the concepts and code in to your application.